# Realloc Causing App Crash

Tags: c, memory, crash, realloc

This question has been asked multiple times, but I've done (from what I can tell) everything that's been mentioned here. Basically, I'm getting 1 character at a time from a TCP socket and I'm building a dynamically growing string with the one character. I can do looping prints and see that the string grows and grows, and then when it gets to 20 characters long, the program crashes.

```
while(FilterAmount != 0)
{
    g_io_channel_read_chars (source,(gchar *) ScanLine,1,&BytesRead,&GlibError);
    printf("Scanline: %s FilterAmount: %ld\n", ScanLine, FilterAmount); 
    //the filters are delimited by \n, munch these off, reset important variables, save the last filter which is complete 

    if(ScanLine[0] == FilterTerminator[0]) { 
        //if the Filter Name actually has a filter in it 
        if(FilterName != NULL){
            FilterArray = FilterName; //save off the filter name
            printf("This is the filter name just added: %s\n", FilterName); 
            FilterArray++; //increment the pointer to point to the next memory location. 
            FilterAmount--; //update how many filters we have left 
            FilterNameCount = 0; //reset how many characters each filter name is
            free(FilterName);
            free(FilterTmp); 
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("else!\n"); 
            //keep track of the string length of the filter
            FilterNameCount++;
            //allocate more memory in the string used to store the filter name + null terminating character
            FilterTmp = (gchar*)realloc(FilterName, FilterNameCount*sizeof(char) + 1);
            if(FilterTmp == NULL)
            {
                free(FilterName);
                printf("Error reallocating memory for the filter name temporary variable!"); 
                return 1; 
            }
            FilterName = FilterTmp; 
            printf("filter name: %s\n", FilterName); 
            //concat the character to the end of the string where space was just made for it. 
            strcat(FilterName, ScanLine);
        }
    }
}
```

This section of code loops and loops whenever we have a non "\n" character in a buffer we're reading data into. The program crashes when allocating the 21st character's location every single time. Here are the pertinent declarations:

```
static gchar *FilterName = NULL, *FilterTmp = NULL;
static gchar ScanLine[9640];
```

Comment: You'll need one extra byte for the NULL character. Also: strcat assumes the original string is null terminated. It is not, at least not the first time. (realloc() does not set the memory to all-zero)

Comment: @wildplasser Well, adding on one character did it. You're awesome. Now it's crashing somewhere else but I'll look into that! The string is declared as NULL, so the first time strcat occurs, isn't it technically "null-terminated" ?

Comment: @wildplasser Strange, now it crashes when I free FilterTmp, but not FilterName....for all intents and purposes they should be the exact same thing.

Comment: Can't tell from here. (where does scanline originate from ? Is it NUL-terminated?, etc) And: reallocating and strcat()ing **once per character** effectively causes your program to use (N*N)/2 running time per character read.

Comment: @wildplasser I updated my code to show where I'm freeing my variables. If you could take a look I would really appreciate it. Also, toss your comment into an answer so I can give you credit for supplying me with the solution to my first problem!

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter Careful of double-free's and overwrites. Best of luck.

Comment: @wildplasser is right. Make sure when you realloc, you realloc a lot more than before. If your current size if N, a common scheme is to realloc N^2 bytes.

Comment: Well, I am not going to *fix your program* . Most of the changes would be stylistic, anyway. I would at least reading one character at a time and putting that in a buffer using strcat() [I don't know the semantics of `g_io_channel_read_chars()` it looks like you are **explicitely** requesting one byte per call. But then: what is the intention of the large scanline-buffer? ]

Comment: @wildpasser Yeah, no worries, you've helped a lot anyways! The purpose of the large buffer is to read in large amounts of data that corresponds to these filters for later plotting on graphs.

Comment: `The string is declared as NULL, so the first time strcat occurs, isn't it technically "null-terminated" ?` You are confusing pointers and characters here. IMHO you should first study C string handling before doing any non-trivial (network)-programming.